# Apply macro to certain list in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an issue applying my macro to a certain list in Google sheets.
Now it applies to ActiveSheet, but I have multiple lists and want this marco for only one.

Current code is:

```
function PriceUpdate() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2')
  spreadsheet.getRange('D:D').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertColumnsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();
};
```

The error I get:

TypeError: spreadsheet.getActiveSheet

Some can help to build working code, Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet, or a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you need?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the sheet's name, so below your `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);`, create an `if` statement that goes:

```
if (spreadsheet.getSheetName() == "Your_Sheet_Name") {
   your code here
}
```

---

***EDIT***

To be able to run the script from another sheet on a specific one (i.e. run on Sheet2 from Sheet1), you can use

```
function test(){
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');

//your code here

}
```

As an example, I ran the code below, and got the following result:

```
function test(){
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
spreadsheet.getRange('C3').setBackground('green');
}
```

I had to create a button to run my script here, but anyway you can call it should work.

[image: Button.exe]

[image]

---

***EDIT 2***

OK, your new code had some issues, because you were not only missing a semicolon, but also trying to `getActiveSheet()` on a variable that already had an "active" sheet parameter. You were also doing it in the same sheet, which was `Sheet2`, so I created a new variable for the current sheet, so things don't get mixed up.

```
function PriceUpdate() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D:D').activate();
  spreadsheet.insertColumnsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 1).activate();
  ss.getRange('E:E').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  ss.getRange('E:E').activate();
  ss.getRange('E:E').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  //spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate(); //not sure why/where you needed it, so I left it out for now.
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Rodrigo! 
That helps only if I'am in that exact sheet. 

Maybe you have a solution how can I run this marco from different sheet? 

eg.: I'm on "sheet1" and want to run this marco on "sheet2" from the sheet I am now, not switching to "sheet2"

Comment: I'll edit the answer to better match your need

Comment: Thanks, Rodrigo! 
Highly appreciate your help.

Unfortunately, now it gives me an error, that is why I cannot apply this code.


I have edited my description with a new code and this errors, Could you check and try this code from your side? I would appreciate that very much! 

Thanks! BTW, is there a way how I can contact you directly? Maybe in case of any projects we can hire you as a developer

Comment: I guess you are missing a semicolon on the first code line, where you're declaring your `spreadsheet` variable.

Comment: I've added my e-mail to my profile, but I'll let you know my coding knowledge might not be enough for full projects, depending on what you need, but feel free to contact me. I would really appreciate the opportunity.

Comment: @DzmitryZhylinski just edited the answer again.